# LINQ: Record list is more than expected records

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have User, UserRoles, Rolelevels, and Shifts tables. And the User's sequence is a foreign key in the UserRoles table and UserRoles's sequence is a foreign key in the RoleLevels table but RoleLevels table will contain more than one record for a RoleLevels sequence. And the Shifts table contains the user sequence. Now I want to retrieve the Shifts table data as one list with a condition that the particular shift's user having a manager role or not, so I have tried like the following but it gives double times the result of the actual result. The total records of Shifts table are 19 but it gives more than 19 records. Where I did go wrong? and how to achieve this logic?

My Linq Query,

```
 private List<ShiftsModel> IsApproverTest(List<Shifts> model)
    {
        //model record count is 19

        var Users = _dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Is_Active == "True").ToList();
        var userroles = _dbContext.UserRoles.Where(x => x.Is_Active == "True").ToList();
        var RoleLevels = _dbContext.RoleLevels.Where(x => x.Is_Active == "Y" && (x.Competencies==1 || x.Competencies==2)).Distinct().ToList();


        var userRoleDetails = (
                               from p in model
                               join u in Users on p.Create_User equals u.UserSeqeunce
                               join ur in userroles on u.UserSeqeunce equals ur.UserSeqeunce
                               join rl in RoleLevels on ur.RoleSeqeunce equals rl.RoleSeqeunce


                               select (new ShiftsModel
                               {
                                   //RoleLevelsList = rl,
                                   Competencies = rl.Competencies,
                                   Shifts_Id = p.Shifts_Id,
                                   Shift_Name = p.Shift_Name,
                                   Shift_Ref_ID = p.Shift_Ref_ID,
                                   Shift_start_Date = p.Shift_start_Date,
                                   Shift_End_Date = p.Shift_End_Date,
                                   Shift_start_Time = p.Shift_start_Time,
                                   Shift_End_Time = p.Shift_End_Time,
                                   Future_Shifts = p.Future_Shifts,
                                   Project_Id = p.Project_Id,
                                   RoleId = p.RoleId == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(p.RoleId),
                                   CPP = p.CPP,
                                   HASP = p.HASP,
                                   TBS = p.TBS,
                                   WPP = p.WPP,
                                   SWP = p.SWP,
                                   Sign_In = p.Sign_In,
                                   Sign_Out = p.Sign_Out,
                                   Status = p.Status,
                                   Remarks = p.Remarks,
                                   Site_Id = p.Site_Id,
                                   Created_Date = p.Created_Date,
                                   modified_Date = p.Modified_Date,
                                   Is_Approved = p.Is_Approved,
                                   Is_Active = (p.Is_Active == "True" || p.Is_Active == "Y") ? true : false
                               })).ToList();

         //userRoleDetailsrecord count is 36 instead of 19 - What's the issue here?
         return userRoleDetails;
    }
```

Comment: Do you only join on unique keys? Can there perhaps be multiple `userroles` with the same `ur.UserSeqeunce` property? (also note the typo: seqEUnce)

Comment: Make your join one by one and count and step by step debug. Or remove tolist get the generated query and debug from there. Or select also the Id of each table and look for duplicate in the result. Those are unknow table with unknow information inside, I don't know how we can find the missing Pk/Fk link.

Comment: @Chrᴉz Yes, join condition is only on unique keys but RoleLevels table contains multiple Rolesequences (same sequence twice) as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Drag and Drop, the following line gives two or more than 1 record for the sequence, but I want to fetch those two records and need check that it contains 1 or 2 value in competencies column.                                                   "join rl in RoleLevels on ur.RoleSeqeunce equals rl.RoleSeqeunce"